# Python windows Как прервать выполнение операции, если она обрабатывается слишком долго

Tags: python, windows, прерывания

Есть операция

```py
texts_a = re.sub(
          r'(<)(script[^>]*>[^<]*(?:<(?!\/script>)[^<]*)*<\/script>|\/?\b[^<>]+>|!(?:--\s*(?:(?:\[if\s*!IE]>\s*-->)?[^-]*(?:-(?!->)-*[^-]*)*)--|\[CDATA[^\]]*(?:](?!]>)[^\]]*)*]])>)',
          r'', str1).lower()
```

для очистки текста от тегов. Обработала с помощь нее большой пласт сайтов, но вот нашла несколько, на которых это выражение не выдает исключений, а просто не прекращает работу.
Как можно обернуть этот запрос, чтобы, если операция не прекращает работу в течении 30сек, например, то просто прервать и идти дальше по коду.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/timeout-decorator/

Comment: Там для windows надо добавлять `use_signals=False`, т.к. в windows нет сигналов.